# Persist Spring Session without Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-session

I am seeking assistance in configuring Spring Boot to persist a Spring Session without using Spring Security.

I started with the [HttpSession JDBC Spring Boot sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/1.2.0.RELEASE//samples/httpsession-jdbc-boot), to persist a Spring Session for a Spring Boot app. However this uses Spring Security.  When removing Spring Security, the session ceases to be persisted in the H2 database. The [XML config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/1.2.0.RELEASE//samples/httpsession-jdbc-xml) and [Java config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/1.2.0.RELEASE//samples/httpsession-jdbc) sample apps do not utilize Spring Security. Thus, not a requirement.

The [guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc-boot.html) states that the **springSessionRepositoryFilter** will create the Spring Session.  However, after removing Spring Security and debugging this filter (SessionRepositoryFilter), the boolean passed to **SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(boolean)** is never set to true.  Thus, the Spring Session is never created and persisted.

Any suggestions on additional configuration required to persist a Spring Session for a Spring Boot app, without Spring Security?

Here are the relevant classes, pom.xml, and application.property file:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SbWebSessionJdbcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SbWebSessionJdbcApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@EnableJdbcHttpSession 
public class HttpSessionConfig {
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.template.cache=false
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-h2.sql
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there isn't anything more in particular you need to configure - you just need to initiate the creation of `HttpSession` and use it according to your needs. For example, the simplest way to achieve this would be to have Spring MVC controller method with `HttpSession` as an argument.

Check out [this repo on Github](https://github.com/vpavic-demos/javacro16-spring-session), in particular `basic-jdbc` module. It's exactly the sample you're looking for - Spring Boot application with Spring Session but without Spring Security.